# Where can I find a good PhP counter?

Tags: statcounter

I want it to be free. Unseen by user. It must be PHP. If the counter need to curl another website I prefer that it's done on background so not to slow down my site.

Any such things? I think I used to see counters, but those are mostly javascripts.

Note:

I don't want to create my own. I want something that's third party.
Also I want php rather than javascript counter.

I tried googling and can't find one I am looking for. Try googling and everyone will teach you how to build one rather than giving one available.

Comment: What kind of counter, a hit counter?

Comment: Otherwise, google ;)

Comment: Please review the above close reason prior to making further edits:  recommendations for third-party resources are considered [off-topic](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site.

Comment: I am not asking for a recommendation. Recommendation means there are 10 options and I want to know which one is the best one. I am asking if there is any like it

Answer (score 1):

If you want a simple hit counter:

```
function countAndShowHits(){
    mysqli_query("UPDATE site_hits SET hits=hits+1 WHERE id=1");
    $stats = mysqli_query("SELECT hits FROM site_hits WHERE id=1")->fetch_assoc();
    return $stats['hits'].' hits';
}

// every time you call it like this, hits will +1:
echo countAndShowHits();
```